# Appending checkboxes values in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a code in which i m checking checkboxes and appending the values to the url.
I m able to append values when only one is checked.but when i check multiple boxes,it appends only latest checked checkbox value.I want like if i check multiple checkboxes.i want to insert those multiple checkbox values separated by comma

following is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="one">one<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="two">two<br>

<script>
$('input[type=checkbox').change(function(){
        window.location.hash = 'check=' + $(this).val();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me correcting my code to append multiple checkboxes value in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a cache of checkboxes by, to use again. Within the `change` event handler function, filter the checkboxes by those that are checked, and map the value of each to an array, with the help of `map()` and `get()`.

Join the values with your desired character(s), and and if it has value, concatenate it with `'check='`

```
$checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox');
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    var values = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;   
    }).get().join(",");
    window.location.hash = values ? 'check=' + values : '';
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E2tet/1/)

Comment: Thanks sir.One small help here if u can do please on code.When i m checking one box and after that when pressing back button and going to previous selection,it keeps the checkbox selected,where as i want it to be selected...

Comment: I'm afraid there's no easy way to get around that. The browser button isn't designed to navigate through different button states using hashing. You'd need to make a check on page load and check your boxes accordingly.